# Replacing (strict) positivity with monotonicity on propositions

Tags: type-theory, inductive-type, positivity

When defining an inductive type, there is a famous "positivity" restriction on the constructor types. For example, an inductive type $\mathsf D$ has constructor $\mathsf c : F(\mathsf D) \to \mathsf D$, where $F(\mathsf D)$ is the type of the constructor argument, and it can contain $\mathsf D$ itself. Then the positivity restriction basically states that the proof assistant needs to see that $F$ is a functor $\mathsf{Type} \to \mathsf{Type}$<sup>(1)</sup>. This is crucial because otherwise the induction principle wouldn't make sense: $$\forall (P : \mathsf D \to \mathsf{Prop}).\left(\forall (\vec x : F(\mathsf D)). \mathtt{fmap}_{F} P \, (\vec x) \to P(\mathsf c\, \vec x)\right) \to \forall x. P(x)$$ where $\mathtt{fmap}_F$ is the map on the morphisms associated with the functor $F$. The proof checker, based on the consideration above, implements some syntactic criteria to ensure functorality, which become known as *positivity*. On the other hand, the "*strictly* positive" criterion, as I view it, is added to avoid size issues similar to that of set theory.

This has led me to wonder if such a criterion can be relaxed on propositions. In languages having definitionally irrelevant (or related weaker notions of) propositions, the propositions can be roughly viewed as a subsingleton, i.e. a subset of the singleton. This avoids all the size issues. Also, the functorality condition degenerates because of the irrelevance. So perhaps for inductive propositions, we can allow $F : \mathsf{Prop} \to \mathsf{Prop}$ to simply be *monotonic*. So if the proof checker can deduce (from some syntactic criteria, or by a user supplied proof) that $F(p) \to F(q)$ whenever $p \to q$, then it should allow this inductive definition. In proof assistants embracing classical logic (at least in $\mathsf{Prop}$), this can be much more powerful. The proof checker might just run a small SAT solver to see if the definition is monotonic.

The question is: does this leads to anything interesting (including possible paradoxes when combined with other features in the type theory)? Pointers to existing literature are also welcome.

(1) : Let's ignore universe levels for now. $\mathsf{Type, Prop}$ are just suggestive notations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Impredicative strict `Prop` supports initial F-algebras for all `F : Prop → Prop` functors. In Coq:

```
Require Import Coq.Unicode.Utf8.

Record Functor : Type := mkFunctor
  {ob : SProp → SProp; hom : ∀ (A B : SProp), (A → B) → ob A → ob B}.

Record Alg (F : Functor) : Type := mkAlg
  {carrier : SProp; phi : F.(ob) carrier → carrier}.

Arguments mkAlg {F}.
Arguments carrier {F}.
Arguments phi {F}.

Definition InitAlg (F : Functor) : Alg F :=
  mkAlg (∀ (P : SProp), (F.(ob) P → P) → P)
        (λ fx P c, c (F.(hom) _ _ (λ g, g P c) fx)).

Definition InitAlgInit (F : Functor)(A : Alg F) (x : (InitAlg F).(carrier)) : A.(carrier) :=
  x (A.(carrier)) (A.(phi)).
```

As you mentioned, all equations can be omitted here because of the irrelevance, and there's no need to consider "dependent" elimination. For ordinary `Prop`, we would need an axiom of irrelevance to do the same. Impredicativity is generally required, else `∀ (P : SProp), (F.(ob) P → P) → P)` doesn't fit in `SProp`.

I couldn't come up with examples of interesting applications of non-strictly positive `SProp`-s, maybe someone else here can.

Comment: Just a small observation: a functor on propositions is precisely a monotone map, and the proof is just the same as for Tarski's fixed point theorem for monotone maps on complete lattices.

Comment: Wouldn't this be useful for type systems? `Inductive typ: term -> type -> SProp := | typ_lam: (typ x A -> typ e B) -> typ (lam x e) (fn A B)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use an impredicative encoding of inductive datatypes?

```
Definition W {A} (B: A → SProp): SProp := ∀ (Q: SProp), (∀ tag, (B tag → Q) → Q) → Q.
Definition sup {A} {B: A → SProp} (tag: A) (f: B tag → W B): W B :=
  λ _ p, p tag (λ b, f b _ p).
Definition W_sind (A: Type) (B: A → SProp) (P: W B → SProp)
           (f: ∀ tag field, (∀ b : B tag, P (field b)) → P (sup tag field)) (w: W B): P w :=
  w (P w) (λ tag field, f tag _ (λ b, field b)).
```

I ape strict positivity here but I'm not quite sure why just using any old functor shouldn't work.

Comment: I second that: the main points of inductive definitions are that 1) they give you better computations than impredicative encodings and 2) they have well-behaved induction principles rather than induction, so that you can show e.g. non-confusion of constructors. But both are unneeded in a propositionally irrelevant setting… People like Werner (see Sets in Types, Types in Sets) do not build propositional inductive types exactly because of this.