# Can you remove strict positivity from mere propositions?

Tags: inductive-type, positivity

You can encode induction [impredicatively](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1243/153). Some minimalist theories dispense entirely with inductive/coinductive types for proof irrelevant impredicative sorts.

But in a practical theorem prover it's nice to have constructors and fields for records even if the underlying semantics are just the impredicative encoding of a fixed point operator $\mu F = \forall x. (F x \rightarrow x)\rightarrow x$.

I suspect in practice though if you just unset strict positivity for inductive proof irrelevant impredicative propositions you'll get a mess instead of the desired semantics of the fixed point operator.

But I'm not sure exactly what would go wrong.

Basically as an example in Coq

```
Unset Strict Positivity.
Inductive weird: SProp := weird_intro (f: weird -> weird).
```

"it would be nice to be like"

```
Definition weird := forall A: SProp, ((A -> A) -> A) -> A.
```

But it probably isn't and things probably break.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow arbitrary fixed points you can inhabit any type.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary type. Suppose we had a type $B$ such that $B \cong B \to A$. Then by Lawvere's fixed point theorem $A$ has the fixed-point property, therefore $\mathrm{id}_A : A \to A$ has a fixed point, so $A$ is inhabited.

Should I write out more details?